# Microsoft AX Dynamics Process Integration through Outbound Ports

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, aif

I would like to know the Process Integration steps.

Through Outbound ports

If any of the event occurs at AX Dynamics, we just want to know that events in the form of XML(Process Integration).

Example: **Sales Order Creation, Customer Creation, Purchase Order Creation**..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outbound ports are only useful for asynchronous communication.

See [AX 2012 Export Data with Outbound ports](http://dynamics-ax-developer.blogspot.dk/2012/09/ax-2012-export-data-with-outbound-ports.html) for an example (using the file system).

The steps to initiate sending data is in the `AIF_SendCustomer`.

As this is no lightweight operation, you may consider logging the records which needs integration in a custom integration table, then doing the processing in batch.

This is done in the `insert` and/or `update` and maybe `delete` method. 
Deletes requires you store the `RecId` field value in the external system to be used for delete requests. The following does not cover this.

For logged table make the following method:

```
void syncRecord()
{
    XXXRecordLog log;
    log.RefTableId = this.TableId;
    log.RefRecId = this.RecId;
    log.insert();
}
```

Then call `this.syncRecord()` in the `insert` and `update` methods.

In the query to the outbound service be sure to exists join your table and the log table. This way only changed records are exported.

Make a batch job to do the transfer using the `AIF_SendCustomer` as a template.
After a synchronous (AifSendMode::Sync) transfer of the records, delete the log records (or mark them transferred).

Finally call `AIFoutboundProcessingService` to flush the file:

```
new AIFoutboundProcessingService().run();
```

Try to keeps things simple. It might be simpler to do a comma file export of the changed records!

Comment: Very helpful and thanks a lot to you, I did what u said now we have received customer information in the form of XML, but we would like to automate it (without user interaction). we are new to X++ & AX dynamics,  would you please suggest us where we need to integrate this code? @ we are looking forward for your vital suggestion.